# PHP Ajax form store dropdown selection as variable

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a php form where the user will select from a dropdown to see a data set.  The data refreshes on the screen with the use of an ajax call. I am using the 'html' datatype so I can refresh the output into the appropriate div section.

The page refreshes with the correct data as expected, but I need to have the dropdown selection stored as a variable in php.  I am not sure how to do this and spent the better part of a day doing research without success.

Here is the form:

```
<form action="" id="postForm" method="POST">
    <select name="name" id="name">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Here is the ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#submit').click(function() {

    $('#waiting').show(500);
    $('#Form').hide(0);
    $('#message').hide(0);

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'html',
        url : '/?tmpl=component',
        data: $('#postForm').serialize(),
        success : function(data){
            $('#waiting').hide(500);
            $('#div-section-to-be-updated').html(data);
            $('#message').text('Your data has been updated').show(500);
            $('#message').hide(4000);               
        }
        ,
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#waiting').hide(500);
            $('#message').removeClass().addClass('error')
                .text('There was an error.').show(500);
            $('#Form').show(500);

        }
    });

    return false;
});
});
```

I want to store "name" as $name when the user clicks submit.

Comment: what exactly response you get on success ?

Comment: Could you post your save data code?

Comment: I am getting all the data back with a valid response (200 OK).  I have if($_POST) {$name = $_POST['name']}; but the variable is not set after the data loads.

Comment: There is only one way to store data in PHP Variable . Create SESSION and store in it.

Answer (score 0):

create session variable and store data in it.

```
session_start();

$_SESSION]['name'] = $_POST['name'];
```

Now you can simply access Session as a PHP variable.

Comment: This usually would work, however I failed to mention that the form exists in Joomla and I am actually posting to "tmpl=component" so I can get the raw html of the data instead of the entire template.  Since I am not posting back to the same page, I can not use $_POST in the php.  Instead I think I have to pass something back using ajax.  I hope I am not confusing this too much.